# Eclipse does not create shared library file in the mixed project (NDK and Java)

Tags: android, android-ndk

I have a project in Eclipse which mixes native and Java code using CDT and ADT. It is really simple - demo project, just as in the android-ndk-r7/ samples/hello-jni

My Android.mk (in the /jni folder) is:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_LDLIBS    := -llog

LOCAL_MODULE    := hlsdrm
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := hlsdrm.cpp

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Everything compiles fine, I can load hlsdrm library by

```
System.loadLibrary("hlsdrm");
```

and call the native functions. But where is the library file placed? There is no libhlsdrm.so shared library in any of the project folders. As I could read, it should create a folder "libs" and place the resulting library in it.

Also, when I try to list libraries which is used by the application process by calling:

```
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
String applicationPackage = this.getApplicationInfo().packageName;
ApplicationInfo ai = pm.getApplicationInfo(applicationPackage, PackageManager.GET_SHARED_LIBRARY_FILES);
String[] soFiles = ai.sharedLibraryFiles;
```

then the soFiles variable is empty...
I have tried to specify the library by `uses-library` value in the application section of the manifest, but after then Android OS refuses to install that application and shows `INSTALL_FAILED_MISSING_SHARED_LIBRARY` error.

Can anybody explain me how can I get my shared library - the physical .so file?

Why the `sharedLibraryFiles` is empty even though the library loads and the native method can be called?

How can I install the application that requires custom shared library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you should create libs folder and set up your project.

Refer to following article to do that:

http://maxters.net/2011/02/android-ndk-builder-for-eclipse-in-windows/

Comment: The Article is great! Unfortunately, it does not work for me. I have exactly followed all the steps, the project compiles without an error but the libs folder is empty and the application crashes right after startup:( Hmm, I spent a few hours by writing the native code and now I am spending the third day by trying to setup the Eclipse project...

Comment: The app is crashing because the System.loadLibrary("hello-jni"); throws an exception... I tried to set PATH C:\cygwin\bin to replace native environment instead of append, and now it creates gdb.setup and gdbserver files in the libs folder, but the library itself is still not built.

Comment: Please post more information such as console messages and logcat messages. Otherwise, I understand your frustration but can't help much. I suspect your NDK or eclipse setup is not right but that's just guessing.

Comment: I finally made it working! I found out that cygwin make is not on the path by typing `make -v` in the cygwin console... So I set PATH variable to c:\cygwin\bin manually in the system and now it works exactly as described in the Article. But there is one thing that remains unclear to me - **why I can't list the loaded shared library by PackageManager?** Anyway, thanks for the help!

Comment: Glad to hear you resolved the problem. As for PackageManager issue, I don't have much experience with it and think you'd better ask a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the library: it should be installed in **/data/data/com.company.yourApp/lib/libhlsdrm.so**

Btw: `soFiles` is not supposed to contain native libraries (.so files), but .jar files. For example if you specify in you manifest `<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />` your soFiles variable will contain **/system/framework/com.google.android.maps.jar**